# Make Python string from json file

Tags: python, json

How can I make a string from json text when the json text contains many, many quotation marks and string escapes?

For example, the following works:

```
json_string = """
{
        "styles":[
                {
                        "label":"Style",
                        "target":{
                                "label":"Target"
                        },
                        "overrides":{
                                "materialProperties":{
                                        "CRYPTO_ID":{
                                                "script":{
                                                        "binding":"name"
                                                }
                                        }
                                }
                        }
                }
        ]
}

"""
```

However this does not, due to the escapes:

```
new_string = """
{
        "styles":[
                {
                        "label":"Style",
                        "target":{
                                "label":"Target",
                                "objectName":"*"
                        },
                        "overrides":{
                                "materialProperties":{
                                        "perObj":{
                                                "script":{
                                                        "code":"cvex myFn(string myObj=\"\"; export string perObj=\"\") { perObj = myObj; }  ",
                                                        "bindings":{
                                                                "myObj":"myObj"
                                                        }
                                                }
                                        }
                                }
                        }
                }
        ]
}
"""
```

Is there a smart way to break this up?  I've had no luck breaking it out into chunks and re-assembling to form the same thing when joined and printed.

Comment: Where does the `new_string` come from? Did you read it from a file? (And then it is not a valid JSON string.) Or did you generate it? If the string is "as-is", you can get some luck with `ast.literal_eval(new_string)`.

Comment: What do you mean by "does not work"? I can copy&paste&"execute" the second string just fine. Or are you saying that ``new_string = """`` is also part of the file?

Comment: @MikeScotty But you cannot read it as JSON with `json.loads`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your string per se is valid JSON, however Python still sees the `\` as special characters.

Use a raw string by prefixing your string with `r`:

```
import json

new_string = r"""
{
        "styles":[
                {
                        "label":"Style",
                        "target":{
                                "label":"Target",
                                "objectName":"*"
                        },
                        "overrides":{
                                "materialProperties":{
                                        "perObj":{
                                                "script":{
                                                        "code":"cvex myFn(string myObj=\"\"; export string perObj=\"\") { perObj = myObj; }  ",
                                                        "bindings":{
                                                                "myObj":"myObj"
                                                        }
                                                }
                                        }
                                }
                        }
                }
        ]
}
"""

json.loads( new_string )
```

Or escape your `\` characters:

```
import json

new_string = """
{
        "styles":[
                {
                        "label":"Style",
                        "target":{
                                "label":"Target",
                                "objectName":"*"
                        },
                        "overrides":{
                                "materialProperties":{
                                        "perObj":{
                                                "script":{
                                                        "code":"cvex myFn(string myObj=\\"\\"; export string perObj=\\"\\") { perObj = myObj; }  ",
                                                        "bindings":{
                                                                "myObj":"myObj"
                                                        }
                                                }
                                        }
                                }
                        }
                }
        ]
}
"""

json.loads( new_string )
```

Comment: Hah!  Success with the escaping escapes! Strangely, the raw string option didn't work.
What I mean by didn't work was that if I wrote anything after the last " " ", the text was considered a multi-line comment.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend reading from an actual JSON file rather than embedding it into your Python code:

```
with open('path/to/file.json') as f:
    json_string = f.read()
```

Or, if you need the JSON parsed into Python objects (dicts, lists etc.):

```
import json

with open('path/to/file.json') as f:
    json_data = json.load(f)
```

Comment: This didn't succeed for whatever reason, but thanks for the suggestion.  Houdini seems to be picky about the contents of the json file and its python interpretation of it.